# Azure Virtual Machine block all access to port except for vnet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure NSG that has port 3128 open. I need to be able to block all connection to the port unless the connection comes from within the VNET. How to I achieve this? Every time I try to set source to Virtual Network I am still able to access it from external IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default NSG allows all traffic within VNET, you can see two rules AllowVnetInBound and AllowVnetOutBound, try to not configure anything to block 3128 port and check if you have access to 3128 from a VM within VNET. You can also try to configure two rules based on [source service tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview), one for internet which blocks port 3128 and the other one virtual network which allows port 3128.